# JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory

Tags: java, jboss, websphere, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I'm migrating one application from Websphere to jboss EAP 6.0. I've made the Datasources on Jboss console. But in my code I've referring this way:

[image: In code]

but while hitting the application from Jboss, it's giving the below error:

> FATAL http-/135.155.175.224:8080-1 dbconn.DBAccess - getDatasource():
>   CRITICAL ERROR: JDBC Naming service exception: JBAS011843: Failed
>   instantiate InitialContextFactory
>   com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory from classloader
>   ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.UPMSSSO.ear.UPMSSSO.war:main"
>   from Service Module Loader

Could anyone please hint the error. Is there any other in for JBoss?

Comment: Remove the setProperty line, which is obviously referring to a WebSphere-specific class that presumably does not exist in your JBoss environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are migrating to Jboss from WebSphere and you are using "**com.ibm.websphere.naming.WasInitialContextFactory**" class, which is WAS specific class, that's why you are getting this error.
Change that to "**org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory**" and then try again. That should resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

All you should have to do is new InitialContext(), without any argument. JNDI is pre-configured with the appropriate properties for you by the app server unless you are looking for remote objects on any other server.

Comment: Hi @Prerak.. thanks for your suggestion, but now I'm getting the below error: FATAL http-/135.155.175.224:8080-1 dbconn.DBAccess - getDatasource(): CRITICAL ERROR: JDBC Naming service exception: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.UPMSSSO.ear.UPMSSSO.war:main" from Service Module Loader"

Comment: can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: Yes you're right. I updated to objProperties.setProperty( Context.URL.PKG.PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); and it worked. Thanks for all your help.